# Evaluating the integral $ \int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(2\theta)\log(\cos\theta) d\theta $

Tags: calculus, integration

How may I compute the following integral?

$$ \int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(2\theta)\log(\cos\theta) d\theta $$

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u=\log(\cos\theta)$ and $dv=\cos2\theta d\theta$ then partial integration comes like this 
$$\log(\cos\theta).\frac{\sin2\theta}{2}-\int\frac{\sin2\theta}{2}.\frac{-\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}d\theta=\log(\cos\theta).\frac{\sin2\theta}{2}+\int \sin^2(\theta)d\theta.$$ Then it follows as $$\begin{align}\int \log(\cos\theta)\cos2\theta d\theta&=\log(\cos\theta).\frac{\sin2\theta}{2}+\int \frac{1-\cos2\theta}{2}d\theta\\ \\ &=\log(\cos\theta).\frac{\sin2\theta}{2}+\frac{\theta-\sin2\theta/2}{2}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\cos2\theta\log\cos\theta\,d\theta\\
&=\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\log\cos\theta\,d\frac{\sin2\theta}{2}\\
&=\left.\log\cos\theta\frac{\sin2\theta}{2}\right|^{\pi/2}_{0}-\frac12\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\sin2\theta d\log\cos\theta\\
&=-\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\sin\theta\cos\theta \frac{-\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\\
&=\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\sin^2\theta d\theta\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{align}